# Facebook SDK PHP 5.0 getLoginUrl() Error 500

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use the examples provided under [Facebook PHP SDK 5.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0) to login to Facebook. I am getting back 500 Internal Server Error. I am using the Baby Plan from HostGator which is running Php 5.5.27 [PHP INFO](http://techcomsgb.com/phpinfo.php) . Is there configuration I would need to add to my server to get things working?

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include the required dependencies.
require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
// Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK v5.
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => '495994870548274',
  'app_secret'            => '593f18b375c9e23d34b9794136cf7158',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://techcomsgb.com/kidneytest/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>'
```

**login-callback.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// Include the required dependencies.
require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );



// Initialize the Facebook PHP SDK v5.
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => '495994870548274',
  'app_secret'            => '593f18b375c9e23d34b9794136cf7158',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['app_id']);
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it     here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper-    >getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
```

// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
    //header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');

Comment: Specify when exactly you get the 500 server errror, also check your error logs.

Comment: @user803271 how u fix that, can u paste the solution here

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too.  Most of the things was in the **hosting side**.  I fixed by doing some things.

1. Check the hosting PHP version 5.4 or higher
2. Check mbstring enabled
3. Set mbstring values in the **php.ini**

[MBString Values Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUO2y.png)

See more: https://benmarshall.me/facebook-php-sdk/#requirements

Then, in the callback.php Facebook Exceptions wasn't working so I change it to the PHP Exception Method like this:

```
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();  
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // There was an error communicating with Graph  
    echo $e->getMessage();       
    exit;  
}
```

Then I get the error message.  It was the date.timezone, I added in the **php.ini** file and now everything is working.

```
[date] date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple error, incorrect file permissions on login-callback.php

Comment: how u fix that, can u paste the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you forgot to place an `app-id` in this section:

```
    // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId({app-id}); // Replace {app-id} with 
    // your app id
    // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate 
    // it here
    //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();
```

Replace the `{app-id}` with your ID and then it should work. I'm surprised no one on Facebook pointed this out.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was the link returned by  `$helper->getLoginUrl()`, so I just replaced https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth with https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize.

```
 $login_url = $login_helper->getLoginUrl('www.yoururl.com/fb-callback.php'), $permissions);
 $login_url = str_replace('https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?', 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?', $login_url);
```

Look at this post for reference [Facebook oauth authorize URL and parameter options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798181/facebook-oauth-authorize-url-and-parameter-options)

"when you want to build the login flow manually you should use /oauth/authorize.. else if you are using javascript/Apps api provided by facbook it uses /dialog/oauth"

Comment: At least you could have explained the downvote so we can know why this is not ok.