# Unable to login through facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

While login wiht fb php sdk, I am getting such kind of error
This page isn’t working

www.facebook.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I had configure my app and my secret key properly according to facebook app and key.

I am not getting why such kind of error is thrown. Please Help me

```
// init app with app id and secret
   FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 
     myappkey,mysecretkey );
  // login helper with redirect_uri
   $helper = new 
  FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://demos.krizna.com/1353/fbconfig.php' );
  try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
 } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
 } catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
 }
   // see if we have a session
 if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
 $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
 $response = $request->execute();
 // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
    $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
/* ---- Session Variables -----*/
    $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
    $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
    $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
/* ---- header location after session ----*/
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

Comment: can you show me bit of code for login

Comment: updated @AhmedGinani

Comment: had you setup current url in live. and check your apache log also check on fb setting Valid OAuth redirect URIs

Comment: yes I had.Actually when I try to log in for first time, its work well but now if i try to login then it  showing error

Comment: assign your profile as a developer or tester ?

Comment: yes its as developer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712867/facebook-sdk-php-5-0-getloginurl-error-500

Comment: remove cache and try again your link works fine for me http://demos.krizna.com/

Comment: visit here/ http://packetcode.com/apps/fblogin5/, login once ans try to login again it will show you blank page. same happening with me

Comment: second time it login directly it's fine need only one time permission and also can't seen error 500 it generate token fine

Comment: yupp you are very correct. I was getting it wrong. Now problem is data is not saving in database although i have fine coded it.